# Groovy: Create an object recursively and easily

Tags: groovy

I need to create an object without having to describe its structure previously. The object is composed of parameters which can themselves be objects (like a json object).

I then want to be able to create an object using this syntax:

```
def a = <TBD>
a.b.c = 'd'
```

Which would result in `a = [b:[c:d]]`

I think one way to achieve that is through withDefaults, but I then have to know the depth of my object in advance.

```
def a = [:].withDefault { [:].withDefault { [:] } }
a.b.c = 'd'
// results in a = [b:[c:d]]
```

Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def M(){ [:].withDefault{ M() } }
def a=M()
a.b.c.d.e.f.g.h = '123'

println a
```

prints

```
[b:[c:[d:[e:[f:[g:[h:123]]]]]]]
```

Comment: Fair enough, thanks. Does it make sense to create an object this way, or would you have used JsonObject or something else ?

Comment: everything that looks nice makes sense )

Comment: @Vivi I'd use map/list literals and collect/collectEntries/collectMany to be as declarative as possible.

Comment: @cfrick So how would it look like using map/list literals ?

Comment: @Vivi The same as the "prints" result basically

Answer (score 0):

A bit more complicated way providing more control:

```
class Endless {

  Map<String,Endless> m = [:]

  def propertyMissing(String name, value) {
    m[name] = value
  }
  
  def propertyMissing(String name) {
    if( !m.containsKey( name ) ) m[ name ] = new Endless()
    m[name] 
  }
  
  String toString(){ m }

}

Endless a = new Endless()

a.b.c.d.e = 42

assert a.toString() == '{b={c={d={e=42}}}}'

assert a.b.c.toString() == '{d={e=42}}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative. I'll stick to withDefault which is shorter and fits my needs.